# CS0311 Error when extending generic types in class headers

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, encapsulation, generic-programming

CS0311: The type 'type1' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method ''. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'type1' to 'type2'.

I have these two classes to start off with:

```
public abstract class Node<N> where N : Node<N> { ... }
public class Pathfinder<N> where N : Node<N> { ... }
```

Then, I have an implementation of Node called Node2D that takes a different generic type, which must extend another class called World.

```
public abstract class World<W> where W : World<W> { ... }
public class Node2D<W> : Node<Node2D<W>> where W : World<W> { ... }
```

I can create an object of type Pathfinder< Node2D< TestWorld > > without any issue (see below). However, when I try to create a Pathfinder using types that extend Node2D< TestWorld >, VSC gives me a CS0311 error. This happens when I make the following specific classes:

```
public class TestWorld : World<TestWorld> { ... }
public class TestNode : Node2D<TestWorld> { ... }

// inside some function
Pathfinder<TestNode> pathfinder = new Pathfinder<TestNode>(); // gives CS0311 error where type1 is TestNode, and type2 is Node<TestNode>
```

And it also happens when I make a class to contain the specific implementation of Pathfinder

```
public class Pathfinder2D<X, W> where X : Node2D<W> where W : World<W> {

    private Pathfinder<X> _pathfinder; // gives CS0311 error where type1 is X, type2 is Node<X>

}
```

How come the original Pathfinder will work for type Node2D< W > for any W, but not for specific implementations of Node2D< W >? If no extensions of generic types were allowed at all, I thought that Node2D< W > would also not work and one could only use the original Node< N > as a type for Pathfinder< N >. Since that worked, I then thought that so long as I have an implementation of Node2D with a specific W, that should work just as well with Pathfinder< N >. If Pathfinder< Node2D< TestWorld > > works, why doesn't Pathfinder< TestNode > where TestNode *is* Node2D< TestWorld >?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CS0311](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0311) states that in this declaration

```
Pathfinder<TestNode> p;
```

`TestNode` must be convertible to `Node<TestNode>`. That's what the constraint for `Pathfinder<T>`'s generic argument states:

```
public class Pathfinder<N> where N : Node<N>
```

But `TestNode` is derived from `Node2D<Testworld>`. And according to the declaration of `Node2D<T>`

```
public class Node2D<W> : Node<Node2D<W>>
```

we know that `TestNode` is actually a `Node<Node2D<Testworld>>`. And that is **not** a `Node<TestNode>`.

So your generic declarations and constraints are contradictionary.

This seems to be a design flaw and how to solve this depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much! My intention was to make Pathfinder<N> work for any N that extends Node, and where instances of Node only communicate with those of the same type (hence why the definition of Node is Node<N> where N : Node<N>). If I make it so that Node doesn't have this definition and is just Node, can I generalize Pathfinder<N> the way I want it to be?